# Circumpolar Equation Derivation

Tags: geometry, mathematical-astronomy

Edit: [Another algebraic solution from Astronomy.stackexchange](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/29310/circumpolar-equation-derivation)

I am trying to understand how the circumpolar star equation works. Although it is astronomy, this part is pretty much just geometry. The equation is this

$\delta + l \geq \frac{\pi}{2}$

The setup is for an observer at latitude $l$, stars whose declination $\delta$ fit this equation are circumpolar. What I cannot get past is how to get from the star's lowest altitude $a$ to there. *Declination is measured from the equator and altitude is measured from the horizon for those who don't know." I know that the angle of the cone made by the rotating star is within the $\frac{\pi}{2}$ limitation. I just can't express it in an algebraic way.

This shows what is meant by circumpolar stars.
[image: Circumpolar stars]

This shows the sort of rotation undergone by the celestial sphere due to the observer's latitude. NCP and SCP are North and South Celestial Poles.
[image: Horizon coordinates]

In the second picture, it is easy to prove that the altitude $a$ is equal to longitude $l$ and that $c = \frac{\pi}{2} - l$. What I need to know is how to go about proving that a star of declination $\delta$ will always have an altitude $a \geq 0$.

Edit: Included pictures in line instead of as a link.

Comment: Declination is measured from the equator going up to 90 at the north pole and -90 at the south. It's the exact same thing as latitude, but for the celestial sphere.

Comment: In the image for horizon coordinates, what are NCP and SCP?

Comment: They are the North and South Celestial Poles. They are projections of the N/S poles of Earth onto the celestial sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See picture below: a star is circumpolar if it lies within the grey cone of half-width $L$, the same as the latitude. Hence declination of such a star must be greater than $\pi/2-L$.

[image]

Comment: This is a very elegant solution. I like it. I did manage to find a solution a little while ago, albeit not as clean as this, but it is more so algebraic instead of geometric. I will post the solution as an answer as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For a star to be circumpolar, the star must, at the very least, come above the horizon.

$0 \leq a \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

In the celestial sphere coordinate system, $c$ can be found to be

$c = \frac{\pi}{2} - \delta$

In the horizon coordinate system, $c$ can be found to be

$c = l - a_{min}$

Therefore

$l - a_{min} = \frac{\pi}{2} - \delta$
$\\$
$l + \delta = \frac{\pi}{2} + a_{min}$

$a_{min}$ can be set to 0 because it is the lower bound for circumpolarity.

$l + \delta = \frac{\pi}{2}$

$\delta$ must be in the cone made by the star's rotation about its declination angle. Therefore

$\frac{\pi}{2} - l \leq \delta$